# A word to describe a posthumous name derived from one's place of death

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, names

After their death, Javanese monarchs in the past were often given names based on the place they died. For example, [the Mataram king Amangkurat I is also known as "Seda-ing-Tegalwangi"](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-94-015-7187-6_5), roughly "He who died in Tegalwangi", because he died in that town. Another monarch, [Seda-ing-Krapyak](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-015-7187-6_3) ("He who died in Krapyak") was even better known by his posthumous name, and history books rarely mentioned his while-alive name.

Is there an adjective to describe these names? It would be handy in sentences like this:

> The Mataram king, known only by his *[adjective name]* name
>   Seda-ing-Krapyak, started a war with ...

The closest I can think is the adjective "posthumous", which explains that the name is not his name while he was alive, but it doesn't quite convey that the name was derived from his place of death. I'm looking for a word that do. I'm open to neologism though I prefer established words.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such tradition in any English-speaking country, so there is no English word for it. "Posthumous" is probably your best bet.

Comment: As a suggestion, that would be also be an **eponymous** name (the city of death being the *eponym* of the monarch). "Posthumous eponymous" might be technically correct -- though it could sound strange at first and it would require an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody is named at birth "El Cid", "Charlemagne" or "Lionhearted" as their only name.
.
English will not supply a general term for a name given after place of death.
But there is a possible option:

> The Mataram king, known only by his storied name Seda-ing-Krapyak, started a war with ...

That will accomplish much of the original idea. And, be a real English term. A footnote would suffice as explanation for what the name meant if required.
In English Language Cultures, we are rarely offered the real names of "El Cid" or "Charlemagne"; they are almost always referred to by what can be called their "storied names"